# Spam in FB Comments, deleted app and still get notifications

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

I've been getting spam comments for months in one of my apps. It got so annoying I decided to delete the App.

However, this has not stopped the issue. The comments still come through and I still get notified. I now can't enter the settings for the App as it's deleted - so how do I turn these notifications off?!